# How to send response to another controller in M2?

Tags: magento2

**Edited**

In Magento 2 I have created a form. it submit data form my controller. So I Want sent data form product save controller after that return my controller. How to I make it? Many thanks!

Comment: use `registry` class.

Comment: mabe in my question is not clear. I edited.